# Where should I put PassOptionsToPackage when loading xcolor?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, color

I'm trying to draw a graph from a table were I have these data:

```
DIM AVRG1 MAX1 MIN1 AVRG2 MAX2 MIN2
```

So I would like to draw 6 lines in my graph:

- 2 means
- 2 for the maximum values
- 2 for the minimum values

Moreover I'd like to "mark" the means with a stronger color, like blue and red, and give the other two a different color wich is less strong, for example cyan or orange.

So I included

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
```

Letting tikz take care of loading xcolor I passed it the following options:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}
```

If I try to load xcolor by itself I get an error while this way works fine.

Then I take the values from the file this way:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width=\linewidth, xmin=0, xmax=8192, ymin=0]
        \addplot [thick, blue] table [mark=none, y=AVRG1, x=DIM]{time1-CPU.data};
        \addplot [small, cyan]table [mark=none, y=MAX1, x=DIM]{time1-CPU.data};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This does work because cyan is in tikz [2]. But let's suppose that instead of cyan I'd like to use Cerulean which is xcolor [1], then I get the following error:

```
 Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/Cerulean' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it
```

How can I make it work?
Thank you!

EDIT: Here is an example

```
\documentclass[epsfig,a4paper,11pt,titlepage,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{plain}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[paperheight=29.7cm,paperwidth=21cm,outer=1.5cm,inner=2.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} 

\singlespacing

\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{ulem} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true, linktocpage=true, pdfstartpage=1, pdfstartview=FitV,
    breaklinks=true, pdfpagemode=UseNone, pageanchor=true, pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,
    plainpages=false, bookmarksnumbered, bookmarksopen=true, bookmarksopenlevel=1,
    hypertexnames=true, pdfhighlight=/O,
    urlcolor=black, linkcolor=black, citecolor=black,
} 
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usegdlibrary{trees}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[cache=false]{minted} 
\setminted{tabsize=4, breaklines, breakanywhere, linenos, mathescape, fontsize=\small}

\definecolor{Ashgrey}{rgb}{0.7, 0.75, 0.71}
\definecolor{Atompurple}{rgb}{0.6, 0.4, 0.8}

\begin{document}
\lstset{
      breakatwhitespace=false,         
      breaklines=true,     
      basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,            
      commentstyle=\color{Ashgey}, 
      keywordstyle=\color{Atompurple}, 
      language=C++, 
      rulecolor=\color{black}, 
      tabsize=4,
      escapeinside={\%*}{*)},
      morekeywords={compute, from, throw, std, ostringstream, __LINE__, __FILE__, define},
}

  \pagenumbering{gobble} 

  \clearpage
  \clearpage
  \pagestyle{plain} 
  \mainmatter

    \begingroup
      \renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{} 
      \renewcommand{\clearpage}{} 
      \titleformat{\chapter}
        {\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{}

      \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0.59in}{0.02in}
      \titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0.20in}{0.02in}
      \titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0.10in}{0.02in}
      \newcommand{\myparagraph}[1]{\paragraph{#1}\mbox{}\\}

      \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[width=\linewidth, xmin=0, xmax=8192, ymin=0, xlabel=\# Clotoidi, ylabel=Tempo medio ($ms$)]
                \addplot [thick, draw=blue] table [mark=none, y=AVRG, x=DIM]{time1-CPU.data};
                \addplot [small, cyan]table [mark=none, y=MAX, x=DIM]{time1-CPU.data};
                \addplot [small, color=Cerulean]table [mark=none, y=MIN, x=DIM]{time1-CPU.data};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}

    \endgroup



    \titleformat{\chapter}
        {\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}{Allegato \thechapter}{1em}{}
    \appendix

\end{document}
```

I've left all the packages inside because I don't know if any of them can clash with another (?).

Compiling this gives:

```
Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `Cerulean'.
```

And

```
Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `tikz@color'.
```

[1] https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors

[2] https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/PGF/TikZ#Color

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you please provide us with a *complete* minimal example, i.e. a small document that starts with `\documentclass`, ends with `\end{document}` and illustrates the problem? (And did you try `color=Cerulean`? You seem to be saying you use `\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}` but the example you use uses `pgfplots` syntax.)

Comment: Yeah sure, the document is quite big, so I'll try to make a smaller one.
I didn't try `color=Cerulean` I shall try right away, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that shows `Cerulean` works just fine:

[image]

### Code:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot [thick, red,      mark=none] {x+3};
        \addplot [thick, Cerulean, mark=none] {-2*x-4};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, solved that, I just had to move `\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}` up... I feel a _little_ bit stupid ahahah... Thanks!

Comment: @icosac: Don't feel stupid, You aren't the first, not the last to make such a mistake. I am sure I have made it many times. Perhaps if you change the title to something along the lines as to where one should place `\PassOptionsToPackage` that might make it easy for other to locate this question when they have that problem.

Comment: Yes, sure thing, changing it right now

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own colours at the start

```
\definecolor{Blue}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.7}
\definecolor{Red}{rgb}{0.7,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{Green}{rgb}{0.0,0.5,0.0}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}
\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}
\definecolor{White}{rgb}{1,1,1}
```